# Combine ResultActions andExpect jsonPath value with JSONCompareMode

Tags: java, matcher, mockmvc, jsonassert

I test my json api like that:

```java
  void testJsonCompareMode() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/test")
        .content("{\"hello\":\"world\"}")
        .contentType(org.springframework.hateoas.MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.somePath").value(
        Matchers.equalTo(JsonPath.parse("[{\"value\": 123}]").json())
      ));
  }
```

I put expected json there as string. Like in this case `[{"value": 123}]`. I would like to be able to use JSONCompareMode functionality. Currently it seems to work like a STRICT  but I would like to get it to work like NON_EXTENSIBLE.

To do this I wanted to implement my own matcher:

```java
  private static class JsonMatcher extends org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher<String> {

    private final String expectedJson;
    private final JSONCompareMode mode;

    public JsonMatcher(String expectedJson, JSONCompareMode mode) {
      this.expectedJson = expectedJson;
      this.mode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(String actualJson) {
      try {
        JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(expectedJson, actualJson, mode);
        return result.passed();
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(org.hamcrest.Description description) {
      description.appendText(expectedJson);
    }
  }
```

and then use it like:

```java
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.somePath").value(
        new JsonMatcher("[{\"value\": 123}]", JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE)
      ));
```

But it always goes to describeTo method and not matchesSafely. After trying many times I could not get it to work.  What is the correct way of doing this?